# How to hide the div on any click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am starting up on jquery and was tryin to create a simple div hide and show effect. The effects seem to work fine but i need that when user clicks on any other part of the document(i. except the hide/show box), the box should hide back. This is the jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/39DzJ/. I have not styled it properly. I wanted the effects to work first.
Can anyone help me out ?
Here's the HTML code :

```
<style>
#mail_floater
{
    background:#fce8bd;
    height:88px;
    width:342px;
    border:1px solid #b7ad02;
    border-radius:5px;
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:50px;
    border-top:none;
    z-index:100;
    padding:0;
    }

#subscribe_user
{
    width:248px;
    height:16px;
    border:1px solid #b7ad02;


}

    #cust_care_floater
{
    background:#fce8bd;
    height:12px;
    width:108px;
    border:1px solid #b7ad02;
    border-radius:2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:2px;
    position:absolute;
    left:450px;
    top:30px;
    border-top:none;
    z-index:100;
    clear:both;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#036f05;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #ccc inset; 
    }

    #closer
{
    float:right;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-top:2px;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    background:url(../images/close.png) no-repeat;

}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" id="subscribe">Subscribe</a>
<a href="#" id="customer_care">Customer care</a>
<div id="mail_floater">
    <h5>Email</h5>       
       <div id="closer"></div>
       <div id="email_input"><form><label>Enter E-mail : </label><span><input type="text" id="subscribe_user" /></span>
       <input type="submit" id="subscribe_me" value="Done" /></form></div>

    </div>
     <div id="cust_care_floater">
     <span style="padding:0px 10px 0 10px;">033-993-99920</span>      
</div>
</body>​
```

The javascript code :

```
$(document).ready (
                   function()
                   {
                       var disp_box=$('#mail_floater');
                       var sub_link=$('#subscribe');
                       var disp_box_2=$('#cust_care_floater');
                       var sub_link_2=$('#customer_care');

                      disp_box.hide();
                      disp_box_2.hide();

                       sub_link.click
                       (
                           function()
                           {

                                disp_box.show();

                           });

                       disp_box.find('#closer').click
                       (
                           function()
                           {                               
                               disp_box.hide();
                           });


                       sub_link_2.click
                       (
                           function()
                           {

                                disp_box_2.show();

                           });




                   });​
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on('click', ':not(.hideDiv)', function(e){
    if($(e.target).is(':not(.hideDiv)')) { //extra check for good measure
         $('.hideDiv').hide();
    }
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/S9fDy/

Comment: @neal thanks for the help. but this is not working in my code. It is hiding the box permanently. The box doesn't show up on click on the anchor after putting this code

Comment: Ya now the effect is working but the div is hiding even when i am clicking within the div or any elements of the div. Any solution for that ?

Comment: @user1720527 fiddle around with it. I am sure you will get it :-D